# Why does my SQL data cause my chart's Y axis to jump to infinity?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I have been trying to build a graph using open Flash Chart 2 in Drupal (Well, the problem isn't related to Drupal or the graphs and  chart module)

For the graph I am fetching the data from a MySQL database. Below is the function which gets the data and generates the graph:

```
function my_module_charts_graphs_test() {

 global $user;
$uname = $user->name;
$sql = "Select total_calorie from health_calorie_consumed where name = '%s'";
$result = db_query($sql,$uname);


  while($row = db_fetch_array($result))
{

    $data[] = $row[total_calorie];

}

$canvas = charts_graphs_get_graph('open-flash');

  $canvas->title = "OpenFlashCharts Chart";
  $canvas->type = "bar_3d";
  $canvas->y_legend = "Y Legend";
  $canvas->colour = '#808000';
  $canvas->width = 700;
  $canvas->height = 300;
  $canvas->y_max=1000;
  $canvas->y_min=0;
  $canvas->y_step=100;
  $canvas->series = array(
    'Some Value' => array(923,623,73,92,5,722,643,156,345),
    //'Page Views' => array_values($data),
  );
  $canvas->x_labels = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');

  // $canvas->x_labels = array_values($data);

  $out = $canvas->get_chart();

  return $out;


}
```

When I run the code, I get the below graph:

[image: preview-1]

So, it works perfectly with a locally declared array. But I need to use the array from SQL. Hence I uncomment and change `$canvas->c_labels` and `$canvas->series`:

```
 $canvas->x_labels = array_values($data); //$data is array from sql query

'Page Views' => array_values($data)
```

Now, to my surprise, I get the below graph:

[image: preview-2]

As we can see, the x_axis values are right as per the query but y_axis says the same values as infinity. Why does it do this?

There is another face to this strange problem. Initially I thought that this approach may not work with `$canvas->series`, but I tried the below code and it worked perfectly:

```
$array = array(0,0,117,207,130,260,207); //these values are that are fetched from sql
$canvas->series = array(
   'some values'=>array_values($array),
   );
```

So this "infinity" problem only appears for arrays fetched from SQL queries and only for the Y axis.

`print_r($data)` of my SQL is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 117 [3] => 207 [4] => 130 [5] => 260 [6] => 207 )
```

Below are some other combinations I tried for $canvas->series and failed...

```
$test = implode(",",$data); // $data is the array fetched from sql
$abcd = "array(".$test.")"; // array(0,0,117,207,130,260,207)

$canvas->series=>array(
      'some value'=>print($abcd), //i tried to print those values in standard format..:p
      );
```

---

```
'some values'=>$abcd, // doesn't work..!
```

---

```
'some values'=>$data, // doesn't work.!
```

Thus I tried everything I can think of with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

wow.. Finally I found the answer, thanks to drupal forums..:)

As it turns out its a type issue..! i.e, if I use the following code, it works..!!

```
<?php
$data[] = (int) $row[total_calorie];
?>
```

I have no idea why is it a type issue. or the reason why this works, but it does solve my problem...! Thanks to everybody for helping me solve it..:)

Comment: as strange as it is I had the same problem when I uploaded my script from Windows to Linux environment. Thanks for sharing. It worked for me too!

Answer (score 0):

Try insert

```
 $data = array();
```

Before the `while($row = db_fetch_array($result))`

And use just

```
 'Page Views' => $data
```

Comment: Didn't work...:( Shows that same "infinity" graph..!!!  Thanks for a cleaner title..:)