# Why do my dates not display on this graph (drupal, php, mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-modules

My mission this week has been to create a sales graph for my Drupal 6, Ubercart and Ubercart Marketplace installation.

I settled on the charts_graphs module and decided to use the Bluff library to graph the data. Although the supported module views_charts allows you to create a wide range of charts, it wasn't able to retrieve the dataset that I needed to graph the sales data. If anyone wants the details of why not, just ask and I'll do my best to elaborate.

So I found an example of the php needed to generate a bluff graph:

```
     <?php 
$canvas = charts_graphs_get_graph('bluff');

      $canvas->title = "Bluff Chart";
      $canvas->type = "line"; // a chart type supported by the charting engine. See further in the doc for the list.
      $canvas->y_legend = "Y Legend";
      $canvas->colour = '#D54C78';
      $canvas->theme = 'keynote';  
      $canvas->series = array(
        'Some Value' => array(9,6,7,9,5,7,6,9,7),
        'Page Views' => array(6,7,9,5,7,6,9,7,3),
      );
      $canvas->x_labels = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');

      $out = $canvas->get_chart();

      return $out;
    }
?>
```

This code then generates this graph...

[image: chart example]

The next stage of course is to get the data from a MySQL query into the graph. This is where I'm outside of my comfort zone because I haven't really done anything previously with PHP.

So after some digging around I found this [post with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180502/why-does-my-sql-data-cause-my-charts-y-axis-to-jump-to-infinity?lq=1) that gave me something to work with. I then used views to help get me started with the SQL. I'm so close I can taste it but this last issue has had me snagged and I can't think of any more searches to do... I'm sure you can relate  with that feeling :)

So this is the code I've developed so far:

```
<?php
    global $user;
$uname = $user->uid;
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT((FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created) + INTERVAL 3600 SECOND), '%d/%m/%Y') as OrderDate, round(SUM(uc_order_products.cost * uc_order_products.qty),2) AS SellerCommission,
round(SUM(uc_order_products.price * uc_order_products.qty),2) AS CustomerPrice
FROM uc_order_products
LEFT JOIN node node_uc_order_products ON uc_order_products.nid = node_uc_order_products.nid 
LEFT JOIN uc_orders uc_orders ON uc_order_products.order_id = uc_orders.order_id 
INNER JOIN users node_uc_order_products__users ON node_uc_order_products.uid = node_uc_order_products__users.uid 
WHERE (node_uc_order_products__users.uid = $uname )
AND (uc_orders.created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-1 DAY)))
AND (uc_orders.order_status in ('payment_received', 'completed'))
GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created))
ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created)) desc, DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created)) desc
LIMIT 31";
$result = db_query($sql,$uname);


  while($row = db_fetch_array($result))
{

    $sellercommission[] = (int) $row[SellerCommission];
    $customerprice[] = (int) $row[CustomerPrice];
    $orderdate[] = (string) $row[OrderDate];

}


  $canvas = charts_graphs_get_graph('bluff');

  $canvas->title = "Volume of sales";
  $canvas->type = "line"; // a chart type supported by the charting engine. See further in the doc for the list.
  $canvas->y_legend = "Y Legend";
  $canvas->colour = '#FFFFFF';
  $canvas->width = '450';
  $canvas->height = '300';
  $canvas->theme = '';  
  $canvas->series = array(
   'Seller Commission' =>array_values($sellercommission),
   'Customer price' =>array_values($customerprice),
  );
  $canvas->x_labels = array_values($orderdate);

  $out = $canvas->get_chart();

  return $out;

?>
```

This code generates a perfect graph, all but the x-axis only displays "//" for the dates...

[image: Generated sales chart]

When I run the query on the database this is the result set that I get. Obviously I replace the placeholder with a UID:

```
09/09/2013  1328.13 1897.32
07/09/2013  455.00  650.00
```

What I can't work out is the type for "$orderdate[] ...." that I should be using. I've tried varchar, int (displays 0), date (breaks it and displays nothing), datetime (breaks it again)... Or perhaps I am retrieving the wrong data as OrderDate in the SQL. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: what do you get when you run the query directly?  or print out the values as you retrieve them?

Comment: I've just updated the post to include the output of running the query directly. Not sure what or how to change the code to print out the values...

Answer (score 0):

So I finally worked it out (complete fluke and don't understand the difference) but this is the final code that worked:

```
<?php
    global $user;
$uname = $user->uid;
$sql = "SELECT concat(DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created)),'/',MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created)),'/',  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created))) as OrderDate, round(SUM(uc_order_products.cost * uc_order_products.qty),2) AS SellerCommission,
round(SUM(uc_order_products.price * uc_order_products.qty),2) AS CustomerPrice
FROM uc_order_products
LEFT JOIN node node_uc_order_products ON uc_order_products.nid = node_uc_order_products.nid 
LEFT JOIN uc_orders uc_orders ON uc_order_products.order_id = uc_orders.order_id 
INNER JOIN users node_uc_order_products__users ON node_uc_order_products.uid = node_uc_order_products__users.uid 
WHERE (node_uc_order_products__users.uid = $uname )
AND (uc_orders.created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())-1 DAY)))
AND (uc_orders.order_status in ('payment_received', 'completed'))
GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created))
ORDER BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created)) desc, DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(uc_orders.created)) asc
LIMIT 31";
$result = db_query($sql,$uname);


  while($row = db_fetch_array($result))
{

    $sellercommission[] = (int) $row[SellerCommission];
    $customerprice[] = (int) $row[CustomerPrice];
    $orderdate[] = (string) $row[OrderDate];

}


  $canvas = charts_graphs_get_graph('bluff');

  $canvas->title = "Volume of sales";
  $canvas->type = "line"; // a chart type supported by the charting engine. See further in the doc for the list.
  $canvas->y_legend = "Y Legend";
  $canvas->colour = '#FFFFFF';
  $canvas->width = '450';
  $canvas->height = '300';
  $canvas->theme = '';  
  $canvas->series = array(
   'Seller Commission' =>array_values($sellercommission),
   'Customer price' =>array_values($customerprice),
  );
  $canvas->x_labels = array_values($orderdate);

  $out = $canvas->get_chart();

  return $out;

?>
```

I basically changed the way I asked for the "OrderDate" in the SQL.... Also corrected a few other minor details...